# Solution to Sylvester-like equation

Tags: matrix-factorization, matrix-equations

I have an equation that is a bit similar to a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation).

The equations is $AXB^T+X=E$, where all variables are matrices.

I could try to inverse $B$ and rewrite the equation as $AX+XB^{-T}=EB^{-T}$, which is then the standard form for the Sylvester equation, but I need to invert $B$, which is usually not a good idea.

Is there a more standard approach to work with this type of equation?

**Edit:**

I can see by doing simple algebra that $X=E-AEB^T+A^2EB^{2T}-A^3EB^{3T}+\dots$ seems to be a solution of the equation $AXB^T+X=E$, if the term $A^nEB^{nT}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Would there be a simple way to compute this infinite sum?

**Edit 2:**

I worked on some potential factorization and I realized that in my problem, $A$ and $B$ are actually symmetrical and positive-definite matrices. The matrix $E$ is not symmetrical (and I don't expect the solution $X$ to be symmetrical either).

So with this information, I rewrite the matrices as $A=P_AD_AP_A^T$ and $B=P_BD_BP_B^T$, which means:
$$P_AD_AP_A^TXP_BD_BP_B^T+X=E$$
$$D_AYD_B+Y=F$$
with $Y=P_A^TXP_B$ and $F=P_A^TEP_B$.
So the matrix $Y$ can be computed as:
$$y_{ij}(1+a_ib_j)=f_{ij}$$
where $a_i$ and $b_j$ are the diagonal entries of $D_A$ and $D_B$ respectively. This equation has stable solutions as $a_i>0$ and $b_j>0$. Then $X=P_AYP_B^T$. So it requires 2 diagonalisations and 4 matrix multiplications, plus one scalar equation per entry.

Is there another matrix factorization approach that could be more efficient here?

Comment: This looks almost like a Stein equation, except you have "+X" instead of "-X" https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/discrete-lyapunov-equation

Comment: That's not a problem, I can have $A'=-A$ or $B'=-B$ and $E'=-E$. I will look at it, as long as there is a way to factor the equation without inverting the matrix then it's better than what I have now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with a more standard form of a Stein equation, sometimes called (generalized?) Discrete Lyapunov Equation

$$AXB - X = C$$

1. Rewrite it in standard linear equation form, use least squares solver, reshape $X$ back into matrix.

$$(B^T\otimes A - I\otimes I)\text{vec}X=\text{vec}C$$

2. Use dedicated solver for Stein equation. They tend to be robust but slow compared to eigenvector solution.
3. Write solution in terms of eigenvalues/eigenvectors.

$$X=T\left( \frac{T^{-1} C B^{-1} U}{\lambda(A)-\lambda(B^{-1})^T}\right)U^{-1}$$
where

- $\lambda(Y)$ is a column vector of eigenvalues of $Y$
- $T$ is a matrix of eigenvectors of $A$ as columns
- $U$ is a matrix of eigenvectors of $B^{-1}$ as columns
- $X/Y$ is pointwise division
- $-$ is subtraction using numpy broadcasting rules

In the underconstrained case, you will have some zeros in denominator. You can simply [skip](https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/1a258310b266ac7ade35b025c9e6fae3) dividing by those entries. I haven't seen this approach in literature, but in experiments this gave me the same solution as the expensive "least squares" form with kronecker products, but much cheaper.

Also note that there are no standalone inverses. Eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $B^{-1}$ can be computed from $B$. Everything else is of the form $A^{-1}B$ or $AB^{-1}$ which is equivalent to solving $AX=B$ or $XA=B$

[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-stein-lyapunov.nb)

Comment: I thought that the discrete Lyupanov equation is $AXA^T-X=C$. In my case, I don't have $A^T=B$.

Comment: Is called Stein equation, equation in Eq 6.1 of http://www.dm.unibo.it/~simoncin/matrixeq.pdf , but Mathematica calls is Discrete Lyapunov

Comment: Thanks for the link. I found in the meantime a "quasi-geometric" solution to the equation but it requires to compute an infinite sum. Is there a simple way to compute this? I added an edit in the question.

Comment: I gave a simple way to compute it in the answer

Comment: and here's an implementation that verifies that both methods work -- https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-stein-lyapunov.nb

Comment: I found that the matrices $A$ and $B$ are actually symmetrical and definite positive so it simplifies greatly the problem. I used your 3rd proposition to find a way to express the solution in terms of the diagonalized matrices $A$ and $B$. It's in the edit 2 (in the question).

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: this answer is essentially useless after the question was updated. If the coefficients $A,B$ are symmetric, these approaches reduce to the simpler closed formula with the eigenvalue decompositions that has already been suggested elsewhere. I don't think there is a simpler / more efficient solution than that.

---

This answer expands on the "dedicated solvers" mentioned in Yaroslav Bulatov's answer.

For these equations there is an algorithm based on reduction to triangular form via Schur factorizations + back-substitution, analogous to the [Bartels-Stewart algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartels%E2%80%93Stewart_algorithm) for Sylvester equations. It is rarely spelled out explicitly in books and sources, but it follows from the same ideas.

The algorithm is "unstructured backward stable", in that it guarantees a low residual $\|AXB -X - C\|$; this follows, for instance, from results for a much more general equation in [this paper of mine](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/nla.2261), but it was surely known before that.

The back-substitution being a for-loop, it's better left to high-performance Fortran or C code. Two packages that implement it are [RECSY](https://people.cs.umu.se/bokg/recent_publications/europar03_IJ_BK_030531.pdf) and [MEPACK](https://www.mpi-magdeburg.mpg.de/projects/mepack), but both seem hard to find. In addition, there is the difficulty of knowing how to link Fortran libraries to whatever language you are using. You can try writing to the authors of MEPACK if you want to go this route. It might be easier to find code for the more general equation $AXB+CXD=E$.

EDIT: also [SLICOT](http://slicot.org/the-control-and-systems-library-slicot/source-archives), with a direct download link to the code.

Comment: Are there dedicated solvers which work for underconstrained Lyapunov/Sylvester?

Comment: Not that I know, just square systems.

Comment: Well I get this for square, but the problem becomes underconstrained when A is numerically singular, which is the case for most large covariance matrices

Comment: If the coefficients are covariance matrices then they are symmetric, so essentially all these solvers reduce to the closed formula with eigenvalues that you have posted above. With that you can implement all sorts of regularization tricks for cheap: Tikhonov, truncating small eigenvalues, pseudoinverses with 1/0 = 0.

Comment: In my case, the matrix is not symmetrical. So I need to look in more details. I am currently checking if I could instead directly work with factored matrices. Thank you for your documents, it's really helpful to see how people look at this in practice.

Comment: I will also look at the iterative process I added in the edit in my post, maybe if the "magnitudes" of $A$ and $B$ are small compared to the solution $X$ then some simple convergence acceleration could also work. I'm not convinced it's faster though... maybe it requires too many matrix multiplications.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I updated the question as the matrices $A$ and $B$ are actually symmetric and definite positive. I provided a closed form solution, as you pointed out in your comment earlier.

Comment: @PC1 Then I don't think there is anything better than the closed formula with the eigendecompositions. I have edited my answer to reflect it. In future when you ask these questions please take some time to specify important assumptions such as "$A,B$ are symmetric and positive definite". :)

Comment: Btw the eigenvalue formula I posted also works for nonsymmetric case, why would one prefer an alternative approach there?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Stability. Unsymmetric eigenvalue decompositions can be arbitrarily unstable. If you try an example with ill-conditioned $T$ and $U$ you'll see that you cannot compute a solution with small residual.